# Random letters? Nope

Tags: cipher

> Yes, this actually happened.

About half a month ago I emailed this string of characters to Beastly Gerbil.

```
]Ñ\wQÝEwp

bin mse txt
```

I did this only because my earlier puzzle I emailed him, uh... didn't work.

The gerbil, it seems, never got around to solving it. But maybe you will.

**What does this string mean?**

Big hint:

> **bin**ary, **m**or**se**, **t**e**xt**

Comment: Have you seen [Code Puzzles: What Not To Do](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)? This doesn't really have much to go off of, so it seems to me that the only way to solve it would be "try random things until English comes out".

Comment: And that’s ^ also a big reason I never could solve it. Cipher guesswork isn’t fun and usually takes a very long time for short strings

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - I added a hint

Comment: @Deusovi - I added a hint

Comment: converting original -> binary -> morse code -> text in that order didn't help me at all: `WQEWP` is what I got

Comment: @TCooper - treat a 0 as no signal and a 1 as signal. Follow Morse code spacing rules as well. :)

Comment: meant to rot13 that :/ oops. But okay, I'll look again in a minute. No fun copy and pasting with online translators

Comment: @TCooper when you forget to rot13 (insert meme man here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is:

> **PUZZ2**

How I got that:

> Convert the original text string from ASCII to binary.
>  That produces this string:
>  010111011101000101011100011101110101000111011101010001010111011101110000
>  Now, treat single 1's as dots, runs of three 1's as dashes and runs of three 0's as separators.
>  That produces:
>  .--. | ..- | --.. | --.. | ..---
>  which encodes PUZZ2

Comment: Correct! Nice work :)

Comment: But what does it mean???

Comment: @Anon - rot13/ chmmyr ahzore gjb ??

Comment: @LannyStrack Haha I am dense